# $(x\in y\land y\in x)\to\bot$ in FOL

Tags: set-theory, alternative-proof

> I want to proof that $$\tag{*}(x\in y\land y\in x)\to\bot$$ in First-Order Logic.

Being $x\in y\land y\in x$ cyclic, it is an infinitely-descending $\in$-chain. Such a thing is excluded in ZFC by the axiom of foundation/regularity (see ["axiom of foundation and infinite sets"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941258)).

Here the mentioned axiom:
$$\forall x \left[\exists y(y\in x)\to \exists y\left(y\in x\land \neg\exists z\left( z\in x\land z\in y\right)\right)\right],$$
or
$$\forall x\,(x\neq \varnothing \rightarrow \exists y\in x\,(y\cap x=\varnothing )).\tag{**}$$

The example $x=\{y\}$ and $y=\{x\}$ satisfies (**), doesn't it?

**EDIT**

I would like my question to be reopened because, although the question 
[Prove that for any two sets $A$ and $B$, $A\notin B$ or $B\notin A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811672/) is similar in content, I would like a formal proof as is mentioned in the title (or I thought to mention by specifying FOL). It is not about *understanding* (the answer to the other question is perfect, actually the comment to this question was enough to understand), but about the formal proof. Thank you.

Comment: In a nutshell, yes, $x$ and $y$ satisfy (**), but $\{x,y\}$, which exists because of Pairing, does not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank you

Comment: Just formalize the proof.

Comment: You should show your attempt at a proof, instead of just asking people to do it for you. It is impossible to learn how to use first-order logic without actually doing enough of it by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof in Fitch ... the FO Con steps are computer-assisted steps but are easily fleshed out into actual formal inference rules. The $c$ introduced on line $6$ is of course the set $\{ a, b \}$ (= $\{ x, y \}$ in your question)

[image]

Comment: Please don't insert images of the results generated by a computer program.  It's like going to Wolfram to ask for a solution to a specific integral, with step-by-step instructions, copying the image, or a screenshot, and uploading it in an answer post.  Here and there, *occasionally*, I can understand its use.  But this program is your go-to for proofs these days.  For future users' sake, please explain in more detail what the shorthand justifications stands for.